# Oracle spool Number rounding

Tags: oracle, spool

I am calculating sum of all sales order (by multiplying quantity and price of a sales order - assume one sale order has only one item and using the sum function) in SQL query and I am spooling the output to a CSV file by using spool C:\scripts\output.csv.

The numeric output I get is truncated/rounded e.g. the SQL output 122393446 is made available in CSV as 122400000.

I tried to google and search on stackoverflow, but I could not get any hints about what can be done to prevent this.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a `xls` issue.

Save as `xls`.

format column -> `number` with 2 decimals for example.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought it might have something to do with the width of the number format which normally is 10 (NUMWIDTH) in sqlplus, but your result numeric width is 9, so that can not be the problem. Please check your query if you use a numeric type that doesn't have the required precission, and thus makes inexact calculations.